# CSS - Is it possible to use a * to parse a class or id?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm adding some styles to some legacy code that dynamically adds a step counter per wizard step of this web app. For instance if the first page of the web wizard is completed the `id` attribute in the html would equal `id="my-wizard-page-name.step1"`.

An example of what the html may look like in the inspector is below:

```
<div id="my-wizard-page.step1">
  <span>This is step 1</span>
</div>
```

After completing step 1 it would then reload and the div would be replaced with:

```
<div id="my-wizard-page.step2">
   <span>This is step 2</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to add styles specific to the wizard page without updating the template `class` or `id`. Is it possible to parse the `id` in my `css` or `less` files.  Im thinking something that would be similar to `#my-wizard-page-name\.step*` or `#my-wizard-page-name*` that would target every step within the page name.

(FYI: the backslah in the `id` is so I can use the `.` without the css assuming its a class on the `id`)

Comment: `[id^="my-wizard-page"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

For your case, the starts with operator would be best: `[id^=my-wizard-page]`

Though, it's probably better to just add a class like `my-wizard-page-step` to each item and use that to select them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do agree I should add a class, I just can't because we aren't editing the templates because its all getting scrapped. They just want a quick css fix.